# Efficient computation of null space of large symbolic matrices?

Tags: matrices, computer-algebra

Are there any computer algebra system/libraries that can compute the null space of a large symbolic matrix in parallel? This problem arises when finding invariant polynomials of a continuous linear group action.

The [same question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23490/efficient-derivation-of-null-space-of-large-symbolic-matrices) has been asked before, but I hope there has been recent progress.

Answer (score 3):

You might look at [LinBox](http://linalg.org/linbox-html/index.html), which does exact linear algebra over, among other things, polynomial rings.